# operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

how to solve the error which contains operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'. The code fallows as :

```
bool AttorneysData()
{
    if (((txtFirstName.Text != "")
                && ((txtSurname.Text != "")
                && (txtAddress.Text
                && (txtTelNo.Text
                && (txtEmail.Text
                && (txtCreatePassword.Text
                && (txtConfirmPassword.Text
                && (cboDisciplineExpertise.Text
                && (cboGeographicalLocation.Text
                && (cboBudgetEstimation.Text
                && (txtNoofIndividuals.Text
                && (cboTypeofClients.Text
                && (txtCompanyName.Text && txtYearsofExperience.Text))))))))))))))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Correct it cant - && is to compare booleans - string is not that.  Do you not meant to have != "" after each text ?

Comment: Another method to read up on for validating strings is [string.IsNullOrEmpty()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why did you stop adding those `!= ""`stuff behind your conditions? Did it for the first two, but afterwards? However all those weird brackets seem cumbersome. Omit them.

Comment: And you don't need the if-statement. Just return the result directly.

Comment: If you need to verify that all those text fields are not empty you could create an array with all of them `TextBox[] fields = new[] {txtFirstName,...};` and then just do `return fields.All(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use logical operators each time. IF you want to chack all strings to inequality to empty string then use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of `!=` operator.

Also there is no reason to use `()` in your expression. You need to use brackets to prioritize operations but in your code there is no prioritets conflict because all operations can executes successively from left to right.

Your `if` statement already contains logical expression that returns boolean result then you can swap it with return operator.

```
return String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text)
            && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSurname.Text)
            && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text)
            && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTelNo.Text)
            && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail.Text)
            && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCreatePassword.Text)
            && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtConfirmPassword.Text)
            && String.IsNullOrEmpty(cboDisciplineExpertise.Text)
            && String.IsNullOrEmpty(cboGeographicalLocation.Text)
            && String.IsNullOrEmpty(cboBudgetEstimation.Text)
            && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNoofIndividuals.Text)
            && String.IsNullOrEmpty(cboTypeofClients.Text)
            && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCompanyName.Text) 
            && String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtYearsofExperience.Text);
```

Answer (score 3):

Every term (`term1 && term2 && ...`) of the if statement's condition has to resolve to a boolean (true/false) value

You could solve it this way:

```
bool AttorneysData()
{
   if (txtFirstName.Text != ""
            && txtSurname.Text != ""
            && txtAddress.Text != ""
            && txtTelNo.Text != ""
            && txtEmail.Text != ""
            && txtCreatePassword.Text != ""
            && txtConfirmPassword.Text != ""
            && cboDisciplineExpertise.Text != ""
            && cboGeographicalLocation.Text != ""
            && cboBudgetEstimation.Text != ""
            && txtNoofIndividuals.Text != ""
            && cboTypeofClients.Text != ""
            && txtCompanyName.Text  != ""
            && txtYearsofExperience.Text != "")
   {
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Or in a slightly more elegant way:

```
return txtFirstName.Text != ""
    && txtSurname.Text != ""
    && txtAddress.Text != ""
    && txtTelNo.Text != ""
    && txtEmail.Text != ""
    && txtCreatePassword.Text != ""
    && txtConfirmPassword.Text != ""
    && cboDisciplineExpertise.Text != ""
    && cboGeographicalLocation.Text != ""
    && cboBudgetEstimation.Text != ""
    && txtNoofIndividuals.Text != ""
    && cboTypeofClients.Text != ""
    && txtCompanyName.Text  != ""
    && txtYearsofExperience.Text != "";
```

Also, consider using the [`string.IsNullOrEmpty` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) which will test for spaces and other empty characters:

```
return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSurname.Text) 
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text) 
    ...
```

Comment: string.IsNullOrEmpty does not checking for spaces and empty chars. IsNullOrWhitespace does.

Comment: thank you it is working. i am having another error it fallows as :txtMin.Text >= "1000" for this i am getting error as operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Comment: @user2801432 you have to convert the string value in a integer (?) value in order to compare it to: `Convert.ToInt32(txtMin.Text) >= 1000` for example